# Sorting a Table with the current View's Model, without plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, model-view-controller, model, sql-order-by

I am still new to MVC and I am trying to find a way to properly sort my current View's data WITHOUT having to install a plugin.

Right now when I click a sort (just an up and down arrrow button by a column title) it will call a query and re-pull all of the data I have but use a different `OrderBy` which is clearly a poor way of doing this.

This is a poor way of sorting since I am recalling data that I already have in my View, but I am not sure how to pass current information from the View to the Controller.

**Q:** How can I get the current data in my View and sort it with my controller? Preferrably without having to install additional plugins and doing it within my Index method.

**RESOURCES**

**Image Representation**
[image]

**Index in the Controller.**

Note: I have a FilterBy and Sort option. My Controller's Index has three `if` options, the first is if neither option is called, the second is if Filter is called, and the third is if Sort is called. As you can see the Sort is just a query with 10 case statements that all recall the data and order it differently.

```
public ActionResult Index(string Filter, string searchString, string Sort)
{
    ViewBag.champ1 = new SelectList(db.championLists, "ID", "Name");
    ViewBag.champ2 = new SelectList(db.championLists, "ID", "Name");
    ViewBag.champ3 = new SelectList(db.championLists, "ID", "Name");
    ViewBag.elo = new SelectList(db.eloLists, "ID", "rank");
    ViewBag.rank = new SelectList(db.rankLists, "ID", "rank");
    ViewBag.role1 = new SelectList(db.roleLists, "ID", "lane");
    ViewBag.role2 = new SelectList(db.roleLists, "ID", "lane");

    // NEITHER FILTER NOR SORT
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sort) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter)))
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.name));
    }   else

        // FILTER STATEMENT
        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter)) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sort)))
        {
            var parameter = 1;
            try
            {
                parameter = Int32.Parse(Filter);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                .Where(x => (parameter == 1 && x.name.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 2 && x.school.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 3 && x.rankList.rank.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 4 && x.eloList.rank.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 5 && x.roleList.lane.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 5 && x.roleList1.lane.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 6 && x.championList.Name.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 6 && x.championList1.Name.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 6 && x.championList2.Name.Contains(searchString)) ||
                    (parameter == 7 && x.summoner.Contains(searchString))
                    ).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.name));
        }

        else
        // SORT STATEMENT
        {

            var Sorter = 1;
            try
            {
                Sorter = Int32.Parse(Sort);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            switch (Sorter)
            {
                case 1:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                               .Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.name));
                case 2:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.name));
                case 3:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.summoner));
                case 4:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.summoner));
                case 5:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.school));
                case 6:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.school));
                case 7:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.eloList.ID));
                case 8:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.eloList.ID));
                case 9:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.rankList.ID));
                case 10:
                    return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                           .Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.rankList.ID));
            }

            return View(db.Users.Include(u => u.championList).Include(u => u.championList1).Include(u => u.championList2).Include(u => u.eloList).Include(u => u.rankList).Include(u => u.roleList).Include(u => u.roleList1)
                .Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.name));
        }
}
```

**View snippet containing the Sort and Filter functions.**

```
<tr>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users"))
        {
            <th class="col-xs-2">
                <h4 style="font-size: x-large; text-align: left">
                    <span style="font-weight: bolder; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                        Name
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up btn btn-sm" value="1" name="Sort" id="sortNameUp" onclick="sortFunction(this, @Model)"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down btn btn-sm" value="2" name="Sort" id="sortNameDown"></button>
                    </span>
                </h4>
            </th>
            <th class="col-xs-2">
                <h4 style="font-size: x-large; text-align: left">
                    <span style="font-weight: bolder; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                        IGN
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up btn btn-sm" value="3" name="Sort" id="sortSummonerUp"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down btn btn-sm" value="4" name="Sort" id="sortSummonerDown"></button>
                    </span>
                </h4>
            </th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">
                <h4 style="font-size:x-large; text-align:left">
                    <span style="font-weight:bolder; margin:0px; padding:0px">
                        School
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up btn btn-sm" value="5" name="Sort" id="sortSchoolUp"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down btn btn-sm" value="6" name="Sort" id="sortSchoolDown"></button>
                    </span>
                </h4>
            </th>

            <th class="col-xs-2">
                <h4 style="font-size: x-large; text-align: left">
                    <span style="font-weight: bolder; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                        Tier
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up btn btn-sm" value="7" name="Sort" id="sortTierUp"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down btn btn-sm" value="8" name="Sort" id="sortTierDown"></button>
                    </span>
                </h4>
            </th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">
                <h4 style="font-size:x-large; text-align:left">
                    <span style="font-weight: bolder; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                        Group

                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up btn btn-sm btn-group" value="9" name="Sort" id="sortMemberUp"></button>
                        <button type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down btn btn-sm btn-group" value="10" name="Sort" id="sortMemberDown"></button>

                    </span>
                </h4>
            </th>
        }
        <th class="col-xs-3">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users"))
            {
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select class="btn btn-group-lg btn-default col-xs-5" style="margin-top: 15px; padding:0px; height: 36px; opacity: 1" data-toggle="dropdown" name="Filter">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected>Filter By:</option>
                        <option value="1">Name</option>
                        <option value="7">Summoner</option>
                        <option value="2">School</option>
                        <option value="3">Standing</option>
                        <option value="4">Tier</option>
                        <option value="5">Role</option>
                        <option value="6">Champion</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <input type="text" name="searchString" class="col-xs-5" style="margin-top: 16px; text-align:center; height:35px; font-size:20px" placeholder="enter text" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-group-lg btn-primary col-xs-2 glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" style="margin-top: 15px; height:36px; opacity:1; padding:0px" value="" />
            }
        </th>
    </tr>
```

I am positive there has be to way to do some sort of POST call to get the current View's data/model and sort by it, but I cannot find anything that does not use a plugin. Can someone assist me in making a Sort function within my Index controller that will allow me to preform an `OrderBy` of the current data?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you figure this out or do you still need some guidance?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks!